# Define word delimiter in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, delimiter

Can Notepad++ be configured to recognise only spaces as word delimiters?

Currently, in the string **"hello!" she said.**, it places word boundaries like this: **"|hello|!" |she |said|.**. I want it to place them like this: **"hello!" |she |said.**

Comment: It looks like user-defined delimiters have been suggested but not implemented in N++. AkelPad has them.

Comment: I found a workaround. Use the Shortcut Mapper to assign Alt+Left and Alt+Right to "Find Next" and "Find Previous". Call up the Find window, and search once for you chosen delimiter character(s). Back in the main window, use Alt+Left/Right to search.

Answer (score 2):

Scintilla (the system underlying N++) defines which characters to treat as word delimiters. N++ itself can't redefine them, but the NppExec plugin can temporarily set them for the current open tab.

So, install NppExec, go to Plugins>NppExec>Execute... and enter `sci_sendmsg 2077  0 @" "`.

Put whichever characters you want to be delimiters between the quotes.

Discussion here: https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/993b6ab9/

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` > `Preferences…` > `Delimiter`.

Select the option to `Add your character as part of word` and enter the chars you want to be treated as alphabet, in your case chars like: `"!,.`

Although, this is usually good to add some special chars as white list, but you may want to have a black list or vise versa. anyway, you can add many chars as you need.